# How large of a USB stick do I need to create the "data media" using Lenovo ThinkVantage Tools?

Tags: backup, usb-flash-drive, thinkpad, system-restore

I just bought a Lenovo ThinkPad X220 Tablet (4294) and I'm trying to use the Factory Recovery Disks application within Lenovo ThinkVantage Tools to create "boot media" and "data media", but I don't have enough space on my 8 GB USB stick for the latter.  This was surprising to me because I [read](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Pre-Installation_steps#Rescue_and_Recovery_Media) that a CD will hold the "boot media" and a DVD will hold the "data media."  My laptop doesn't have an optical drive, so I can't burn any disk.  (Don't get me started on my Sony DRX-710UL external burner that [won't work](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929461) with Windows 7.)

Anyway, this is the error I get, including the misspelling:

> Create Recovery Media
>
> No enough temporary disk space in D drive, Create Recovery Media will exit now.
>
> OK

Judging from some [other](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkVantage-Technologies/x120e-recovery-media-will-not-fit-on-8gb-USB-stick/td-p/443115) [posts](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge/EDGE-11-Will-I-need-a-R-W-USB-CD-DVD-drive/td-p/395395) I'm not the only person having this trouble.

[Another post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkVantage-Technologies/Restore-System-from-Q-Lenovo-Recovery-Drive/td-p/553257) got me looking into a file called cdrivebackup.wim and I'm thinking that perhaps I need to get a USB stick that is as large or larger than Q:\FactoryRecovery, which for me is 9,592,796,014 bytes (~9 GB), per below.  Does that sounds right?

```
C:\Users\pdurbin>dir Q:FactoryRecovery
 Volume in drive Q is Lenovo_Recovery
 Volume Serial Number is 640D-D557

 Directory of Q:\FactoryRecovery

10/15/2011  02:28 AM             3,986 bcdinfo.txt
10/15/2011  02:28 AM     9,290,524,252 cdrivebackup.wim
10/15/2011  02:28 AM               956 RECOVERY.INI
10/15/2011  02:07 AM       302,266,820 sdrivebackup.wim
               4 File(s)  9,592,796,014 bytes
               0 Dir(s)     810,397,696 bytes free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir Q:FactoryRecovery` *did* provide a good estimate of how much space I needed.  In my case, the final amount of disk used by the "data media" was 9,593,602,048 bytes (8.9 GB) so a 16 GB USB stick was big enough.